# Существуют ли пунктуационные синонимы?

Tags: пунктуация, синонимы

Если да, то чем они различаются?

Comment: Почему Вы не принимаете ответы? Вы не знаете, как это делается?

Answer (score 2):

Синонимами можно назвать знаки, которые могут заменять друг друга, если они выражают сходные отношения между частями предложения. К примеру, близки по значению запятая и точка с запятой, о чем говорится в приведенной ниже статье:

"Следующий знак препинания, который мы рассмотрим – это точка с запятой. **Она в какой-то мере является синонимом и точки, и запятой**, а в другой мере противоположна каждой из них".[Что такое пунктуация? Правила пунктуации. Проверка пунктуации](http://fb.ru/article/137912/chto-takoe-punktuatsiya-pravila-punktuatsii-proverka-punktuatsii)

**Мне этот вопрос кажется малоизученным и неактуальным**, так как знаки-синонимы должны соответствовать сходной интонационной структуре.  Например, тире, двоеточие и запятая могут заменять друг друга, если между частями предложения  наблюдается понижение (но не повышение) тона: Гулять не пойдем, на улице дождь. Гулять не пойдем: на улице дождь.Гулять не пойдем - на улице дождь.

Данные примеры в устной речи различаются **по длительности паузы**, а разница в семантике определяется **желанием автора обозначать или не обозначать  причинно-следственные отношения.**

Но  интонация в правописании у нас практически не изучается, поэтому **эта тема может рассматриваться только чисто формально, без особой практической пользы.** В реальности же (при свободном письме) пользователи этой синонимией знаков, разумеется,  пользуются, но  на интуитивном уровне.

Comment: Да, Серж, спасибо, исправила.